# Randomizing random.randrange(len(???)) using specific percentages

Tags: python, random, probability, percentage, rate

Item a is more expensive than item b and c, so it has lower chance to print. Item e is extra rare.
Item a has %20 drop rate while b and c has %70. Item e has a chance of %1. Item d is "No gift for you today." How???

```
items = ["item a","item b","item c","item d","item e"]
randItem = random(randrange(items))
print(randItem)
```